# Is it okay to get all the elements of a database collection just for the react-select autocomplete?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, forms, react-select

I'm using 'react-select' for react multi select and autocomplete field.
it has a prop called options, which must contain all the possible options for the autocomplete.
In my case, these options are coming from a database, it's the names of users as label and their id as value, and my only solution now is to call a get for all the collection of users and get their names and IDs, but I'm pretty sure there's an optimization thing around, can anyone help ?

Comment: What are you trying to optimise? What is slow?

Comment: You imagine me having a collection of 10K users, I'll need to put them all in a state just to put the users' names and IDs in options of that react-select.
Is that normal ?

Comment: The only way to resolve this is to perform such optimisation on the BE with performing queries to DB which would select limited amount of records. You won't be able to provide such an optimisation on FE.

Comment: @WiktorBednarz, I see man. Thank you .. is there an example on github about that ? on optimizing it on BE !

Comment: Maybe try a typeahead component if that suits the UI? That way the list can be populated from the backend after the user types a few characters, narrowing the result set.

Comment: @TixeN I think that this article could be a nice starting point for you: https://medium.com/@piyush.neo/a-complete-guide-for-lighting-fast-autocomplete-search-suggestion-82a68a83bf68

Comment: @WiktorBednarz Okay I will, thank you again ^_^